# Run Configuration - running multiple blocking scripts

Tags: pycharm

I want to run, say 4 different server scripts from four different script files all at once.

I tried to set up the run configuration as follows:

[image]

However since servers listen in a loop, each of the four programs are blocking.

In the present setting(as seen above), Pycharm runs the first server specified in "Before Launch" section below and stops at it.

Is there a way to run all the four server scripts at once using `Run Configurations` ?

Comment: Any findings related to this topic, relevant to share ?

Comment: 0
down vote
However since servers listen in a loop, each of the four programs are blocking.

What do you mean that the the four programs are blocking? Could you send a minimal exaple of, for example, two of those files?

Comment: He means that each configuration runs a program that does not have an explicit termination.  For example a  webserver.  A webserver will "always on" or "blocking" since you want to work on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm - Run two scripts/configurations in one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687239/pycharm-run-two-scripts-configurations-in-one-click)