# Run two scripts/configurations in one click

Tags: pycharm

I'm working on a `Django` project and I have classic configuration so I just click on "run" and development server is running. But I need to run Celery from console every time I'm working on this project.

Is it possible to add the `celery` command so both are started just using one click?

[image]

I want to automatically run/stop this command:

```
celery -A myproject.celery worker -l info --beat
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["Compound" Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-compound-run-configuration.html) can start a group of other Run Configurations in parallel.

You will need the `BashSupport` plugin in order to use a Bash script as a run configuration. Then, with your command `celery -A myproject.celery worker -l info --beat` in `celery.sh`, you can create a compound run configuration , e.g.

[image: example compound configuration]